# Org-mode: manually re-order headlines from column view

Tags: org-mode, sorting

I love that we can quickly re-order our outlines with the `M-<Up|Down>` arrow keys. For whatever reason, I can't get this to work in column view. I would like to enable this behavior.

Any ideas how to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Column-view is just an overlay that doesn't alter the buffer.  Have you tried turning on and off column view to see if that updates everything visually after you perform a re-order?  Or, does column-view somehow prevent you from performing a re-order -- if so, what happens when you try to perform a re-order (anything)?

Comment: When I hit `M-Up/Down` I get an error "`Text in read-only: "Type e to edit property"`...

Comment: It appears that the authors of the `org-column` library have made a conscious decision to place a `read-only` text property as part of the `org-columns-display-here` function.  You will probably need to just turn off column view when editing and then turn it back on again when you are done.  The message is telling you that you can type the letter "e" to edit a value, but beyond that, you are probably out of luck except to the extent that you turn off column-view.  By the way, the title of the question says `sorting` -- your question is not really about sorting (which is a separate animal).

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. I would love to find some custom eLisp to override this. But... I suppose I can always toggle back and forth, until a solution is found.

Comment: I wrote an elisp command to sort columns from column view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113931/13466303). It could be modified to reorder instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun org-columns-move-subtree-down (&optional arg)
  "Move the current subtree down ARG headlines, from column view."
  (interactive "p")
  (org-columns-quit)
  (org-move-subtree-down arg)
  (org-columns))

(defun org-columns-move-subtree-up (&optional arg)
  "Move the current subtree up ARG headlines, from column view."
  (interactive "p")
    (org-columns-quit)
  (org-move-subtree-up arg)
  (org-columns))

(org-defkey org-columns-map [(meta down)] #'org-columns-move-subtree-down)
(org-defkey org-columns-map [(meta up)] #'org-columns-move-subtree-up)
```